# c# BitmapMetadata photoshop:DateCreated

Tags: c#, bitmap, metadata, photoshop, datecreated

Using C#, `BitmapMetadata` working with images from Adobe Lightroom.
I have not been able to get to the `photoshop:DateCreated` field, even though I can see it in notepad, and in Lightroom. I have not found a solution that works for me. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
// This works for getting lots of the items I see in Lightroom. 
BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(str_imagePath)); 
BitmapMetadata meta = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;

// can find Title, Rating, Subject, keyWords, authors, comment, copyright 
Console.WriteLine(" Title: {0}", meta.Title);
Console.WriteLine("  Rating: {0}", meta.Rating);

// can not get to photoshop:DateCreated - hoping query would work
if (meta.ContainsQuery(@"photoshop:DateCreated"))
     Console.WriteLine("  contains1 ");

// briefly, here is what I can see in notepad: photoshop string comes right after rating            

 xmp:Rating="2"  
 photoshop:DateCreated="1916-08-01T07:00:00"
```

I have included [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BsvZQncHW2OF9jZWhQQWp3UXc/view?usp=sharing) to my tiff file.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please format your code sample